# Landing page for SilverStripe Website

Tags: silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe blog website set up on my domain and hosting. However, for now when people visit my URL I want them to come to a landing coming soon page as I want to do some marketing and create a small database of users prior to launch.

How can I do this without having to remove the SilverStripe Project from the hosting?

I thought it may be as simple as adding a new index.php page. However, even with this it comes straight into my blog website rather than the landing page I made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by using this [SilverStripe Maintenance Mode Module](https://github.com/thisisbd/silverstripe-maintenance-mode).

This module allows an administrator to put site in offline mode with 503 status to display a 'Coming Soon', 'Under Construction' or 'Down for Maintenance' Page to regular visitors, whilst allowing a logged in admin user to browse and make changes to the site.

You can customise the maintenance page to say whatever you like.